# Which Config File Takes Precedence In Rails - config/application.rb or config/environments/#{RAILS_ENV}.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails config, you can put configuration settings in either `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/#{production|staging|development}.rb` When faced with conflicting configuration options, which file's config option is taken as the winner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment-specific config takes precedence over `application.rb`. You can see this in the docs for `Rails::Application`. The initial load (point 3) happens in `application.rb`, and environments have the chance to override in point 5.

```
Booting process
The application is also responsible for setting up and executing the booting process. From the moment you require “config/application.rb” in your app, the booting process goes like this:

1)  require "config/boot.rb" to set up load paths
2)  require railties and engines
3)  Define Rails.application as "class MyApp::Application < Rails::Application"
4)  Run config.before_configuration callbacks
5)  Load config/environments/ENV.rb
6)  Run config.before_initialize callbacks
7)  Run Railtie#initializer defined by railties, engines and application.
    One by one, each engine sets up its load paths, routes and runs its config/initializers/* files.
8)  Custom Railtie#initializers added by railties, engines and applications are executed
9)  Build the middleware stack and run to_prepare callbacks
10) Run config.before_eager_load and eager_load! if eager_load is true
11) Run config.after_initialize callbacks
```

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html